# PB8 Command Button Enabled

Tags: powerbuilder

i am using PB version 8 though i also used higher version of PB but we have this application that was developed in version 8. i have created an external datawindow and assigned 3 command buttons inside it and i just found out that there was no Enabled properties in the datawindow design. i constructed a line of script: 
dw_1.Object.b_edit[1].Enabled = False and placed it in constructor event of dw_1. compiled it and run the program. And unfortunately, it returned an error message of "Error accessing external object property b_edit..."

Is there any other way around on how can i enabled a command button which resides inside the datawindow in PB 8.?
I also checked with the higher version of PB that its possible to have Enabled properties of command button inside a datawindow.

Answer (score 0):

i think you should try this two:

```
<DW Control Name>.Modify("<Buttonname>.Enabled=<Yes or No>")
```

or

```
<DW Control Name>.Object.<Buttonname>.Enabled='<Yes or No>'
```

The problem with your code is maybe, with the [1], and the "false". You can also browse the properties for datawindow control and settings in the following menu:

File\New\Tool\Datawindow Syntax

In your example it should look like:

```
dw_1.Modify("b_edit.Enabled=No")
```

If b_edit is the name of your button control!

Br

Gábor